# Tables loading on a dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-table, onchange

I have a dropdown and I want to make different tables appear below it, according to the selected option.

I've already seen it here:
[Javascript - onchange within <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368219/javascript-onchange-within-option/12478169)

I was able to replicate that, but I really don't know how to add more options/tables.

Can someone help? This is the code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('transfer_reason');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('otherdetail');
     eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.value === "other") {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('other2');
     eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.value === "z") {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="transfer_reason" name="transfer_reason">
<option value="">Motivo</option>
    <option value="x">Reason 1</option>
    <option value="y">Reason 2</option>
    <option value="z">Reason 3</option>
    <option value="other">Other Reason</option>
</select>
<br>
<table border="1" id="otherdetail" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<th>Versão 11</th><th>Versão 12</th><th>Justificativas</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1</td><td>Angelina</td><td>Delhi</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="other2" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<th>Versão 11</th><th>Versão 12</th><th>Justificativas</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1</td><td>Galeno</td><td>Delhi</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As it is now, only the table with id="other2" is loading correctly, while the other table is not.

Comment: Please post the code directly in your question. You will delete the dropbox file in some near future and then it will be gone.

Comment: You say you don't know how to add more options/tables...does that mean you don't know how to add more to the HTML, or it's the Javascript you're having problems with?  And, like yunzen says, you should post your code.

Comment: Just having problems with the JS. I could add one table just right, but failed when I wanted to add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way than what exists in the example. If you use the table ID values in your drop-down the whole thing gets easier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('transfer_reason');
    var selVal;
    hideTables();
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        hideTables();    
         selVal = eSelect[eSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById(selVal).style.display = "block";
    }

}

function hideTables() {
     var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for(var x=0;x<tables.length;x++) {
        tables[x].style.display = "none";
    }
}    
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
  <select id="transfer_reason" name="transfer_reason">
        <option value="">Motivo</option>
        <option value="Table1">Reason 1</option>
        <option value="Table2">Reason 2</option>
        <option value="Table3">Reason 3</option>
        <option value="Table4">Other Reason</option>
</select>

<table id="Table1"><tr><td>#1#</td></tr></table>

<table id="Table2"><tr><td>#2#</td></tr></table> 

... etc ...
```

Comment: Work as a charm. Thank you very much, Diodeus =]